# makefile is not working at raspbian, but working at ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying compile c project in raspbian.
My c project is linux ut100c driver source code.
This project compiled in ubuntu.

**Makefile:**

```
CFLAGS =  -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -fPIC
LIBS = -lpthread -lcurl -lm
OBJS = dvb2dvb_server.o psi_read.o psi_create.o crc32.o json.o parse_config.o ringbuffer.o
TESTS = test.o psi_read.o psi_create.o crc32.o json.o parse_config.o ringbuffer.o

all: dvb2dvb_server

dvb2dvb_server: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o dvb2dvb_server $(OBJS)

test: $(TESTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS) -o test $(TESTS)


dvb2dvb_server.o: dvb2dvb_server.c dvb2dvb_server.h psi_read.h psi_create.h crc32.h ringbuffer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o dvb2dvb_server.o dvb2dvb_server.c

psi_create.o: psi_create.c dvb2dvb_server.h psi_create.h crc32.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o psi_create.o psi_create.c

psi_read.o: psi_read.c dvb2dvb_server.h psi_read.h crc32.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o psi_read.o psi_read.c

crc32.o: crc32.c crc32.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o crc32.o crc32.c

json.o: json.c json.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o json.o json.c -lm

parse_config.o: parse_config.c parse_config.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o parse_config.o parse_config.c

ringbuffer.o: ringbuffer.c ringbuffer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o ringbuffer.o ringbuffer.c


clean:
    rm -f dvb2dvb_server $(OBJS) *~
```

How I can compile this in ubuntu?

**Error Log:**

```
cc -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -lpthread -lcurl -lm -o dvb2dvb_server dvb2dvb_server.o psi_read.o psi_create.o crc32.o json.o parse_config.o ringbuffer.o
dvb2dvb_server.o: In function `curl_thread':
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:205: undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:206: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:207: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:208: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:209: undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:210: undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
/home/ubuntu/Desktop/dvb2dvb-server/dvb2dvb_server.c:212: undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
```

**Updated:**
added error log as text

Comment: Please show the error as text not an image + also what part of the error do you want expanding?

Comment: Sounds like you have a different version of libcurl on the two systems.   Run `ldconfig -v` on both systems, see where it's pulling curl from, and then do an `objdump -s libcurl.so` on both of them to compare the symbols.   You may need to update your library or your library search path.

Comment: The order of library link options on the command line matters to some linkers.  Move them to the end: `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)`.  Even if that doesn't solve your problem, it's better form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Updated as @John Bollinger

```
dvb2dvb_server: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o dvb2dvb_server $(OBJS) $(LIBS)
```

And, I can compile without problem